# Listing results from two connected tables

Tags: php, mysql, list

I have two tables as following:

**files**

id   |   path   |   filename

**changes**

id |   file_id   |   change

**file_id** field is connected to the id which is in files table.

What I do with these tables is storing which files are changed and what changes are done in a file.

What I want to do is listing the files and listing the changes which were made in that table under file.

What is the best and most optimized way to do that in PHP?

Thank you for your help.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a JOIN query:

```
SELECT files.*,changes.change FROM files 
   LEFT JOIN changes ON change.file_id = files.id
   ORDER BY files.id;
```

This will get you a result set with each row containing:

- id
- filename
- path
- change

With the use of the `ORDER BY` query, you can store the last :

```
$fileId = null;
foreach ($results as $result) {
    if ($fileId != $result['id']) {
        echo "{$result['filename']}\n";
        $fileId = $result['id'];
    }

    echo "  {$result['change']}\n";
}
```

Comment: I can get the result using JOIN query. What I want to implement is listing the results like: FILE 1 => CHANGES, FILE 2 => CHANGES and so on. Thank you for the answer by the way.

Comment: @netcoder I think he needs a `RIGHT JOIN` (or the tables reversed...) and an `ORDER BY file_id` so that he has all changes per file (instead of just 1), grouped by file.

Comment: @jeroen: Sorry I haven't figured that's what you wanted. I updated my answer.

Comment: @netcoder sorry to be a pain, but he needs `FROM changes LEFT JOIN files` in order to get all the changes for a file. Perhaps even a normal join would be better to also get the files that haven´t changed.

Comment: Thank you all for answers.
Actually I want a list like this:

Path\Filename
    >change 1
    >change 2
    >change 3
Path\Filename
    >change 1
    >change 2

Comment: @Chris: Did you try my above code. It should do it (without the formatting).

Comment: Yeah, I tried it. What I want to do is pretty much alike but I want File path and file name listed before listing the changes. Something like ordered list.

Comment: My bad. I've been using my previous JOIN query. The revised answer did the trick. Thank you for the answer @netcoder.